# InvalidProgramException when trying to parse VB.Net code with Roslyn

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I'm trying to parse VB.Net code using Roslyn, but it keeps throwing the `InvalidProgramException` (Jit compiler encountered a limitation..). A similar code works perfectly with C#.

This is my code:

```cs
var source = "Public Module Module1 \r\n Public Sub X() \r\n End Sub \r\n End Module";
var syntaxTree = Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.SyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
var compilation = Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.Create("MyCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] {syntaxTree});
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
```

The exception is thrown on the last line.

**Update** Here's the stack trace:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.
HResult: -2146233030
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.SeparatedSyntaxList`1..ctor(SyntaxNode node, Int32 index)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.CompilationUnitSyntax.get_Members()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.DeclarationTreeBuilder.VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitSyntax node)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.CompilationUnitSyntax.Accept[TResult](SyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.SyntaxVisitor`1.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.DeclarationTreeBuilder.ForDeclaration(SyntaxNode node)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.DeclarationTreeBuilder.ForTree(SyntaxTree tree, ReadOnlyArray`1 rootNamespace, String scriptClassName, Boolean isSubmission)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.ForTree(SyntaxTree tree, CompilationOptions options, Boolean isSubmission)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation._Closure$__11._Lambda$__59()
   в System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   в System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   в System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.DeclarationTable.GetLatestRootDeclarationIfAny(Boolean includeEmbedded)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.DeclarationTable.GetMergedReferenceDirectives()
   в System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   в System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   в System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.DeclarationTable.get_ReferenceDirectives()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.get_ReferenceDirectives()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.CommonAssemblyManager`3.GetCompilationReferences(TCompilation compilation, DiagnosticBag diagnostics, List`1 references, IDictionary`2& boundReferenceDirectives, List`1& referenceDirectiveLocations)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.CommonAssemblyManager`3.ResolveMetadataReferences(TCompilation compilation, List`1 references, IDictionary`2& boundReferenceDirectiveMap, ReadOnlyArray`1& boundReferenceDirectives, List`1 assemblies, List`1 modules, DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.AssemblyManager.CreateSourceAssemblyForCompilation(Compilation compilation, Dictionary`2& referencedAssembliesMap, Dictionary`2& referencedModulesMap, IDictionary`2& boundReferenceDirectiveMap, ReadOnlyArray`1& boundReferenceDirectives, SourceAssemblySymbol& assemblySymbol, DiagnosticBag& diagnostics)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.AssemblyManager.CreateSourceAssemblyForCompilation(Compilation compilation)
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.EnsureSourceAssemblyCreated()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.get_SourceAssembly()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.get_Assembly()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.get_SourceModule()
   в Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(SyntaxTree syntaxTree)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any exception from this code. Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I don't see anything in `SeparatedSyntaxList\`1..ctor` that could cause such exception. You could try [reporting this as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Answer (score 1):

This exception typically indicates that the program itself is corrupt. If you're able to provide a crash dump file, please do so.

Also, verify that your assemblies haven't been corrupted in some way. All Roslyn binaries we ship are digitially signed, so check if your Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic.dll has a valid signature. Find the DLL, go under File Properties in Windows Explorer, Digital Signatures tab, and hit details. Verify you see "the signature is OK."

Comment: I am able to run this code as a Console app without any problem. However, the problem appears when I use this code in a Web app (using the WebDev server). Could it be some kind of incompatibility? I have no such problem when I use the CSharp compiler..

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the exception is being thrown when I use the code on my Web site only, and then the Web site runs on either VisualStudio Development Server or IIS Express. Also running it via TestDriven.net and Gallio (might be just old versions). The code runs fine with a Console app or IIS full.

I still consider this a bug, since a similar code that uses the CSharp compiler runs just fine.